# Installed packages in sublime text but after reboot, sublime text reverts to default

Tags: installation, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Sublime Text 3.2.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed several packages such as compare-this and export-html in Sublime Text. The packages appear in  These packages worked fine but when I shut down my laptop and start up again, all the installed packages are gone. I have to reinstall them. It seems Sublime Text reverted to a fresh install.

Additional Info: I am using dual-boot with Win 10. All OS are installed in an SSD and I have another hard disk for files storage. Sublime Text is installed in the SSD.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your configuration for Sublime is stored in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/` ; if that folder gets removed, then so does your configuration for Sublime (removing this folder is exactly how you would revert to a fresh state manually, for example). Is your home directory being modified at all between restarts?

Comment: I installed some packages, and the packages are in ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/  Then I reboot, check that the packages are still in the folder. I startup Sublime and the packages are deleted immediately.

Comment: How did you install them? Packages being removed are a symptom of taking a `sublime-package` file that was installed by Package Control on one computer and dropping them into a different copy of Sublime.

Comment: I used Package Control and everything is done on my laptop. I didn't copy/paste the packages' folders into ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/ from another computer.

Comment: Do you see any messages in the console after startup from Package Control, or anything that looks like it's decided to remove a package?

Answer (score 0):

So I have fixed the problem. In Sublime-text top menu, go to Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - Default

There should be a line:

> "remove_orphaned": true,

Now go to Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User

Add this line:

> "remove_orphaned": false

Save the file and the problem should be fixed.